# Tibco BW designer hangs when I try to open the xpath formula builder

Tags: tibco, businessworks

Every time I try to launch the XPath formula builder in the designer, I have to kill the designer process. Am I missing some configuration?

UPDATE :

Fixed this issue. This happens when you have a secondary display.
Find the document Designer5.prefs whic is usually in .TIBCO folder.
Find the line xpath.dialog.lastWindowLocation and change the value to 0,0

Answer (score 2):

Deleting that file doesn't solve the issue.
My solution consists of changing the value in `xpath.dialog.lastWindowLocation`

Answer (score 0):

Also whenever you install tibco make sure creating a new TIBCO_HOME folder..and do not use the earlier one .
Also in DESGINER.TRA file make 512 mb as 1024MB

Answer (score 0):

Another option is delete the Designer5.pref file and restart the Designer. that solved my issue.